# ARM: May I do direct memory accesses to a range returned by ioremap_nocache() [without using ioread*()/iowrite*()]?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm using a TI AM3358 SoC, running an ARM Cortex-A8 processor, which runs Linux 3.12. I enabled a child device of the GPMC node in the device tree, which probes my driver, and in there I call `ioremap_nocache()` with the resource provided by the device tree node to get an uncached region.

The reason I'm requesting no cache is that it's not an actual memory device which is connected to the GPMC bus, which would of course benefit from the processor cache, but an FPGA device. So accesses need to always go through the actual wires.

When I do this:

```
u16 __iomem *addr = ioremap_nocache(...);

iowrite16(1, &addr[0]);
iowrite16(1, &addr[1]);
iowrite16(1, &addr[2]);
iowrite16(1, &addr[3]);
ioread16(&addr[0]);
ioread16(&addr[1]);
ioread16(&addr[2]);
ioread16(&addr[3]);
```

I see the 8 accesses are done on the wires using a logic analyzer. However, when I do this:

```
u16 v;

addr[0] = 1;
addr[1] = 1;
addr[2] = 1;
addr[3] = 1;
v = addr[0];
v = addr[1];
v = addr[2];
v = addr[3];
```

I see the four write accesses, but not the subsequent read accesses.

Am I missing something? What would be the difference here between `ioread16()` and a direct memory access, knowing that the whole GPMC range is supposed to be addressable just like memory?

Could this behaviour be the result of any compiler optimization which can be avoided? I didn't look at the generated instructions yet, but until then, maybe someone experienced enough has something interesting to reply.

Comment: You need to check the generated code. That's a pretty easy optimization for a compiler to make. Add `volatile` where necessary.

Comment: Yes, it might be just that. I'll have a look and come back with the results.

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of `ioread16`? That's specifically designed to both have correct ordering semantics and not be optimised away. Any compiler with optimisation turned on is going to throw away a simple assignment to a variable which is never used.

Comment: Yes, I see ARM's `readw()` does a "volatile" load followed by a data memory barrier, so that must help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ioread*()` and `iowrite*()`, on ARM, perform a data memory barrier followed by a `volatile` access, e.g.:

```
#define readb(c)                ({ u8  __v = readb_relaxed(c); __iormb(); __v; })
#define readw(c)                ({ u16 __v = readw_relaxed(c); __iormb(); __v; })
#define readl(c)                ({ u32 __v = readl_relaxed(c); __iormb(); __v; })

#define writeb(v,c)             ({ __iowmb(); writeb_relaxed(v,c); })
#define writew(v,c)             ({ __iowmb(); writew_relaxed(v,c); })
#define writel(v,c)             ({ __iowmb(); writel_relaxed(v,c); })
```

`__raw_read*()` and `__raw_write*()` (where `*` is `b`, `w`, or `l`) may be used for direct reads/writes. They do the exact single instruction needed for those operations, casting the address pointer to a `volatile` pointer.

`__raw_writew()` example (store register, halfword):

```
#define __raw_writew __raw_writew
static inline void __raw_writew(u16 val, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
        asm volatile("strh %1, %0"
                     : "+Q" (*(volatile u16 __force *)addr)
                     : "r" (val));
}
```

Beware, though, that those two functions do not insert any barrier, so you should call `rmb()` (read memory barrier) and `wmb()` (write memory barrier) anywhere you want your memory accesses to be ordered.